# How to pronounce multiple consecutive third tones in a sentence

Tags: pronunciation

I learned that a third tone character is pronounced as a second tone if it's followed by another third tone character. My question is, how do I pronounce a sentence that has three or more consecutive third tone characters? Should I pronounce all of them except the last one as second tones?

Comment: excerpt from http://www.zhihu.com/question/21783429  三个上声音节相连，如果后面没有紧跟着其他音节，也不带什么语气，末尾音节一般不变调。开头和当中的上声音节有两种变调情况：

1．当词语的结构是“双单格”时，即2＋1结构，开头和当中的上声音节调值变为35（阳平）。例如：

水彩笔 shuǐcǎibǐ 选举法 xuǎnjǔfǎ 展览馆 zhǎnlǎnguǎn 考古所 kǎogǔsuǒ

2．当词语的结构是“单双格”时，即1＋2结构，开头音节处在被强调的逻辑重音时，读作“半上 （half-third tone）”，调值变为21（阴平），当中音节则按两上变调规律变为35（阳平）。例如：

冷处理 lěngchǔlǐ 小两口 xiǎoliǎngkǒu 好导演 hǎodǎoyǎn 海产品 hǎichǎnpǐn

Comment: as to be expected this question has been discussed in English, search web using e.g. "How to pronounce 3 consecutive 3rd tones" it seems most of these answers do not allow for 半上 (half-third tone) as above reference

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Chinese_phonology#Tone_sandhi see: Third tone sandhi and also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Chinese_phonology#Stress.2C_rhythm_and_intonation

Comment: Using 可口可乐 as an example, it doesn't have a single third tone: kékóu-kélè.

Comment: An answer is here [Generalize consecutive third tones change rule](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/21395/generalize-consecutive-third-tones-change-rule).